# Differentiate between app update and fresh install

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have an app with version 1.0 on the AppStore. Now I would like to release 1.1 as an update. When the app launches, is there a way to differentiate between an app that was updated from 1.0 and an app that was already downloaded as 1.1? For instance to display a list of new features to existing features, but show the complete introduction to new users.
Unfortunately, I stored no entries in NSUserDefaults with version 1.0 and I have no documents that I could search for.

Comment: @rmaddy That doesn't seem like a reliable method to me. Depending on whether the actual release date happens to be before or after the date I hardcode, I will either have some updates classified as new installs, or the other way around.

Comment: Do some searching. I found that one after a quick search. I know there are others covering this question. See what you can find. There's even one listed under the Related question to this question.

Comment: @rmaddy I did. And I've seen those. One answer uses swizzling, which would result in a rejection. The others all suggest checking NSUserDefaults or the Documents folder. That's why I mentioned, that I can't do that.

Comment: @Jawap Using  swizzling won't result a rejection.